# Application Architect vs. Systems Architect vs. Enterprise Architect?

Tags: terminology

So many buzzwords. Not sure if I need to start playing BS Bingo or not. And I'm not trying to be cynical. But I've heard many people with these various titles. There never seems to be a clear delineation between the three. Or there's a lot of domain crossover between the three. Actually, another I've seen while looking around here on Stackoverflow has been "Solutions Architect" as well. But that one doesn't seem to be so prevalent in other places.

There are questions here and there with vague answers. But I'd like definative answers to this. Please assume I'm still relatively new to software stuff and that I'm trying to map out a career path.

Oh, and please be gentle folks; this most definitely is not a duplicate question. Neither is it an aggregate. So kindly leave it alone.  Xp

Comment: You really don't need the word "architect" for the question - the architect defines the overall structure in all three domains.  Then the question reduces to "what's the difference between an application, a system, and an enterprise?  oh, and a solution?"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Like any other such term, these terms are used differently in different places, and are sometimes interchangeable.  Here's what the differences typically are:

- The **Application Architect** is is what many of us just call the Architect.  The person responsible for the highest levels of design and scope for a particular solution/project.  You'd bother using *Application* in the title if there were other types of architects around, and you wanted it clear that this person worries mainly about a particular application.
- The **Enterprise Architect** is worried
  about *all* of a companies solutions. 
  How they rely on each other, how they
  use each other, how efficient can
  their common upkeep and improvement
  be made.  He thinks about how all the solutions together support the company's mission.  Only a larger company could warrant this grandiose title.  The Enterprise Architect is a big shot who meets with the CIO, CTO, and other such big shots.
- The **Systems Architect** might be considered to have a wider scope than the Application Architect, and less than an Enterprise Architect.  This title is sometimes the exact same thing as Application Architect - big shot on a *particular* project.  Sometimes the *System* part of the title cannotes a wider scope:  person who duties include software but also *hardware* and *IT*, or someone worried about multiple projects.

Comment: Adding some real world background: I was hired by a financial institution in 2008 as an Application Architect.  My company was purchased, and my title became Solution Architect.  Exact same job, slightly different title.  The meaning of "architect" is what the employer says it is.

Comment: Right!  And I think if they had called you System Architect, that would have made sense too.  I think the meaning of *System Architect* in particular is only clear in the context of the other types or architects you have running around a particular place.  Systems Architect is often a job title, for a job where the person acts as the *Application Architect* on various projects.

Comment: Just as you need "light" to define "darkness" or vice versa, you need your employer to define these roles and their job descriptions, outside of this context its a "pateto" "potato" problem ;)

Answer (score 17):

I've encountered quite a few architects with varying titles over the years, and I definitely have my own view on the role of each of them, however it does tend to vary from company to company, and even more so from country to country.

*Enterprise Architect* - responsible for strategic thinking, roadmaps, principles, and governance of the entire enterprise. Usually has a close relationship with the business, vendors, and senior IT management.

*Solutions or Systems Architect* - responsible for desiging a high level solution to a specific set of business requirements, within the framework laid down by the enterprise architecture team. This solution may span multiple applications.

*Integration or SOA Architect* - responsible for the integration and/or business service strategy and governance. Since this role usually spans the entire enterprise it is often performed by an EA, however an integration architect will usually work at a more detailed and technical level than an EA.  In a SOA, an integration architect may also be a member (or even leader) of the centre of excellence (or integration competency centre)

*Information Architect* - responsible for defining data models, master data management / ownership solutions, and data quality processes to support transactional, reference data, and reporting systems throughout the enterprise.  Often performed by an EA.

*Application Architect* - responsible for implementation of, and processes within, a specific application or suite of applications. The application in question may be bespoke of a customised of-the-shelf product.  Should have deep knowledge of the product/application and will often be consulted by other architects as part of a larger solution

Those are the most common titles in my experience, but there are other architecture roles that you'll see from time-to-time:

- Technical Architect (for me this is the same as an application architect but others may disagree
- Business Architect (defines business strategy and processes)
- Infrastructure Architect (servers, platform decisions, and often security)
- Network Architect (obvious)

Answer (score 6):

Well it sounds like your in school still but looking into the business world and expecting titles on the cards to be as structured as a degree system... its not.

Truth be told the business title is either a company specific job-title to support the internal pay-grade system or the org charts. Its hard to take from one company to another on anything more than very general terms. Its not really a benchmark like a BA or PHD.

As far as titles and job roles go, teams in companies generally break down into Infrastructure (Server setup and networking), and Applications (DB admins, developers) groups. There is a lot of variance by company but that seems to be pretty universal.

I think your best bet in planning is to decide what you like to do, and then study to do it very well. Along the way as an IT guy you have to pick up a little in all areas to be very effective in any area anyway..

Good luck!

Comment: Didn't mean to imply I'm interested in titles. Just interested in specific definitions and how they fit into the industry. Since I've not been able to nail down definitions in searching, coupled with the above text, I'd say these "titles" are merely subjective and can't be classified in scientific terms vs. artistic liberty in definitions. That was my main goal to figure out. Though I believe there are some actual cirtifications out there one can receive, I have also read that it's illegal in some states to even say you're an "architect" of any kind without the appropriate legal credentials.

Answer (score 2):

What each means really is determined by the company you work for; what some call a Solution Architect others call a System Architect. They're all (assumed) senior positions with some implied oversight of system/software design but aside from that I've never seen one definition that will make everyone happy. "Enterprise" does imply some scope to the position, but it's arguably no different than "Systems" (again, depends on the company). Application Architect usually makes me think of someone who's been around as a senior developer for a while and HR needed a new title to reward performance. Sort of like the way some massive companies lob the "Vice President" title around to the point it doesn't really mean anything besides how many vacation days you get.

Comment: yeah, good point, upvote.  What titles are often *really* about is (a) making all the consultants in your company appear more impressive to your clients ("wow, ABC Consulting sent a *Senior Systems Architect* to help me out.  I'm so lucky!") or (b) trying to make someone feel special without giving them more money.  Or (c) shutting someone up who is friends with the CEO, but who you don't want to *really* give more responsibility to.

Answer (score 1):

What the Hell..

Architect:
Application - designs applications
Systems - designs multiple applications and coordinates into a system
Enterprise - designs systems and coordinates with the other non system aspects of the business enterprise.

Let's not forget salary, bonus and how much time you spend on worrying about your title.

Comment: In a nutshell, what you're saying is what I though. Kind of intuitive if you ask me. But I one person's description regarding the "Systems" definition that doesn't fit the model you described. Just seems very subjective overall.

Comment: Not sure subjective and intuitive are the same. My 'model' is so broad I can't imagine another that doesn't fit.

Comment: Let's just say there are some out there in authority who mix & match words with definitions at will and just expect everyone else to fall in line behind what they're saying as being the truth.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Enterprise Architect is biggest role of all. He has to have complete technological implementation knowledge.

Comment: Yes, *that person* has to have complete technological implementation knowledge.

Comment: "he"................